# Problemas para remover elemento @ManyToMany com @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou com problemas ao excluir um relacionamento @ManyToMany no JPA. Resumindo, tenho 3 tabelas: USUARIO, PERMISSAO e USUARIO_PERMISSAO que é o relacionamento das anteriores, o relacionamento é N para N. O problema é que não sei ao certo como fazer para remover ou adiconar uma nova permissao a um usuario **ja existente** na base, segue modelo simplificado:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_USUARIO")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @Column(name="NO_USUARIO", unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
    private String noUsuario;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="TB_USUARIO_PERMISSAO"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="NO_USUARIO", nullable=false)
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="NO_METODO", referencedColumnName="NO_METODO", nullable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="NO_PERMISSAO", referencedColumnName="NO_PERMISSAO", nullable=false))
            }
        )
    private List<Permissao> permissoes;
}



@Entity
@Table(name="TB_PERMISSAO")
public class Permissao {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PermissaoPK id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="permissoes")
    private List<Usuario> usuarios;
}
```

Meu problema esta com o mapeamento do campo **permissoes** da classe **Usuario**, quando insiro um novo Usuario no banco ja adicionando a permissão funciona, segue codigo que funciona:

```
Usuario usuario = new Usuario("USUARIO_01");
usuario.getPermissoes().add(permissao); //permissao ja cadastrada no banco
entityManager.persist(usuario);
```

Esse codigo insere corretamente um novo usuario e também o relacionamento com a permissao na tabela TB_USUARIO_PERMISSAO. O problema agora é excluir as permissoes, vamos supor que um usuario tenha 2 permissoes e eu queira excluir uma delas, como eu faco isso? Segue exemplo que **não funciona**:

```
Usuario usuario = entityManager.find(Usuario.class, "USUARIO_01");
usuario.getPermissoes().remove(0);
entityManager.merge(usuario);
```

Esse codigo a cima não funciona, será que tenho que mudar o mapeamento, sei la, talvez criando uma entidade UsuarioPermissao? O mapeamento esta da forma que a engine de engenharia reversa criou.. Se eu remover um usuario, automaticamente as permissao são excluidas. Meu problema esta em **excluir** e também **adicionar** uma nova permissao de um usuario ja cadastrado no banco. Também ja usei Cascade e sem sucesso.

Podem ajudar?

**Nota: para simplificar mudei o codigo pelo editor, pode ter algum erro que se colocar na IDE não vai compilar, a ideia é mostrar a base. Tambem tentei outras formas para remover/adicionar que achei melhor não citar ja que não funcionaram**

Grato!

Comment: "esse código não funciona": dá algum erro ou simplesmente não remove o relacionamento?

Comment: Quer remover apenas uma das permissões, mas não são elas, independente uma da outra e de seus usuários? O usuario apenas faz uso dessa permissão existente, ao deletar um usuario o relacionamento com essa permissão some, porém a permissão continua existindo para que seja usada por outros usuários, entendi errado?

Comment: @BrunoCésar nao da nenhum erro, simplesmente nenhuma ação é executada.. estou com debug do hibernate ativo e realmente não faz nada.

Comment: @DouglasGaldino Ao excluir o usuario apenas o relacionamento da permissao (tb_usuario_permissao) com o usuario é apagado. Quando digo que não consigo remover uma permissão do usuario, me refiro a modificar apenas a tabela de relacionamento tb_usuario_permissao, ou seja, tb_permissao em nenhuma momento deve ser alterada.

Comment: @wchagas entendi. Inclui uma resposta com o que foi possível entender, como não é um exemplo completamente executável inferi algumas coisas de forma a funcionar. Veja se lhe atende, se não, inclua mais detalhes :)

Comment: @BrunoCésar obrigado bruno, vou analisar!

Comment: Caso tentar remover todas relações referente a determinado usuário, funciona normalmente?

Comment: Você não está adicionando o usuário na permissão, só está adicionando a permissão no usuário. Veja isso.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro de tudo acredito que seu mapeamento pode ser simplificado, principalmente a tabela de junção.

Para centralizar o mapeamento da chave primária das entidades criei uma `BaseEntity`, assim:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

}
```

A entidade `Usuario` ficou assim:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_usuario")
public class Usuario extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "no_usuario", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String nome;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}) 
    @JoinTable(name = "tb_usuario_permissao", joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario", nullable = false)
            }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_permissao", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
            }
    )
    private Set<Permissao> permissoes;

}
```

Aqui pontuamos o seguinte:

- não misture lógica de negócio com seu modelo de dados, então não use o nome do usuário como a chave primária, considere-a uma chave única e tenha
- inclusão do cascade: não sei se você precisará disto, inclui apenas para não precisar persistir cada permissão separadamente. Para mais detalhes sobre o comportamento de cada tipo veja a [especificação da JPA](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)
- já que temos uma chave primária em `tb_permissao` não faz sentido termos duas colunas de junção que referenciam colunas de negócio. Normalmente há mais de uma coluna de junção quando ela é uma chave estrangeira pra outra tabela, por exemplo.

A entidade `Permissao`, ficou assim:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_permissao")
public class Permissao extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "no_permissao", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "no_metodo", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String metodo;

}
```

A menos que você realmente precise saber todos os usuários tem uma determinada permissão não precisa mapear, mesmo neste caso eu preferiria fazer uma consulta.

Agora, a parte da remoção, vamo observar este trecho:

```
usuario.getPermissoes().remove(0);
```

Bom, com este modelo acima a remoção ocorreu conforme o desejado, logicamente quando há uma ou mais permissões.

como exemplo (estou usando [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)), o teste de inserção ficou assim:

```
final Permissao permissao1 = Permissao.builder().nome("permissao1").metodo("metodo1").build();
em.persist(permissao1);

final Permissao permissao2 = Permissao.builder().nome("permissao2").metodo("metodo2").build();
em.persist(permissao2);

final Usuario usuario = Usuario.builder().nome("Bruno").permissao(permissao1).permissao(permissao2).build();
em.persist(usuario);
```

E assim:

```
final Permissao permissao3 = Permissao.builder().nome("permissao3").metodo("metodo3").build();
final Permissao permissao4 = Permissao.builder().nome("permissao4").metodo("metodo4").build();

final Usuario usuario = Usuario.builder().nome("César").permissao(permissao3).permissao(permissao4).build();
em.persist(usuario);
```

A remoção assim:

```
final Usuario usuario = em.find(Usuario.class, 1L);
usuario.getPermissoes().remove(0);
em.merge(usuario);
```

E a inclusão de uma nova permissão a um usuário já existente assim:

```
final Permissao permissao = em.find(Permissao.class, 1L);
final Usuario usuario = em.find(Usuario.class, 1L);
usuario.getPermissoes().add(permissao);
em.merge(usuario);
```

E de uma ainda não existente assim:

```
final Permissao permissao5 = Permissao.builder().nome("permissao5").metodo("metodo5").build();
final Usuario usuario = em.find(Usuario.class, 1L);
usuario.getPermissoes().add(permissao5);
em.merge(usuario);
```

Como não informou maiores detalhes na sua pergunta, caso não solucione o seu problema peço que informe mais detalhes, como a sua `PermissaoPK` (para saber se realmente precisa).

Comment: Realmente a questão da chave poderia ser melhor, porem o banco ja esta em producao.. tirando as modificações no modelo, o restante eu estava fazendo igual ao seu exemplo, vou analisar novamente pois devo estar esquecendo de algum detalhe no momento dos testes. dp reotrno, obrigado pelo exemplo!

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que consiga o `id` do **usuário** e **permissão** que deseja ser removido, pode ser feito o `delete` manualmente através de uma query.

Ex:

```
entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM USUARIO_PERMISSAO up WHERE up.usuarioId = :usuarioId AND up.permissaoId = :permissaoId");
```

> Porque ao utilizar `remove(index)` como esta tentando utilizar, mesmo
>   que estivesse parcialmente funcionando, a ordem da posição `List<T>`
>   para receber os valores referente a aquele *usuário*, pode acabar não
>   sendo a permissão desejada assim tendo inconsistência ao deletar.

Na solução acima, a alteração ocorre somente na *tabela* que mantém os **relacionamentos**, tendo os **ids**, fica explicito o que você quer remover.